# My search macro is not returning the search value

Tags: vba, excel

I have compiled a code that searches for a value in a excel file say for example that value is 'D0'. When i tested the Search code separately it worked. But, when i combine my search code with a code that loops through files it does not work . The problem found is that the search does not returns the value.I have pointed out in the code, the Part thats not working. All, I am trying to do is to combine a search code with a code which will pick up file names written in the column of an excel sheet and then open those files and execute the search code.

```
Sub MyMacro()
Dim MyCell, Rng As Range
Dim Fname As String
Dim FirstAddress As String



 Set Rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A6")    'sets the range to Read from

 For Each MyCell In Rng                       'checks each cell in range
    If MyCell <> "" Then                      'Picks up the file name present in the cell

       MyCell.Activate                            'Activates the cell
       Fname = ActiveCell.Value                   'Assigns the value of the cell to fname


       Application.ScreenUpdating = False


       Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\" & Fname, True, True) 
                                                       'opens the file 

       wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate                'activates the opened workbook

       Call Find_String                                'calls the search code

       wb.Close SaveChanges:=False



    End If


  Next       
End Sub

Sub Find_String()

Dim FirstAddress As String
Dim MySearch As Variant
Dim Rng As Range
Dim I As Long
Dim strMyValu
Dim Axis
Dim wb As Workbook


MySearch = Array("D0")                     'value that needs to be searched

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook                    'trying to bring the opened workbook as active sheet 

With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:H100")



 For I = LBound(MySearch) To UBound(MySearch)

   Set Rng = .Find(What:=MySearch(I), _After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _SearchDirection:=xlNext, _MatchCase:=False)

   If Not Rng Is Nothing Then      'this is the part not working
                                   'It should return the search value instead it returns nothing 
              'so as the value returned by the code is nothing and hence the code goes to endif

   FirstAddress = Rng.Address

     Do

        Sheets("Sheet1").Select                   'Selecting sheet1 on opened file
        Rng.Activate                               
        strMyValue = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value 'Copying the offset value of the located cell
        Axis = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value       


       Workbooks("book22.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate  
                       'Activating the workbook where i want to paste the result


       Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = strMyValue
       Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Axis

       wb.Activate                      
                       'Activating the opened file again for loop to search for more values


       Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
       Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress
    End If
  Next I


  End With
  End Sub
```

Kindly help.
I am struck. I am new to VBA. So, unable to figure out what went wrong as when i tested the search code seperately it worked. Is it something related to the activation of file opened?
 When i open a file it is not activated and hence search runs on the workbook that contains the macro instead of the opened file and so its unable to return search value???

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is the naming of your variables and the changing workbook and worksheet contexts.  Be specific in you naming of variables so that you know what it should be and it will help you debug.

Also you don't need to activate workbooks and worksheets to get values from the ranges and cells.  just getting a reference to the sheet,range cell will allow you to get what you need.

See it this does the trick for you.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MyMacro()
    Dim MyCell, Rng As Range
    Dim Fname As String
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    Dim searchSheet As Worksheet
    Dim copyToSheet As Worksheet
    Dim copyToWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim searchWorkbook As Workbook

    Set copyToWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\workbook22.xlsx")
    Set copyToSheet = copyToWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")


    Set Rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A6")    'sets the range to Read from

    For Each MyCell In Rng                       'checks each cell in range
       If MyCell <> "" Then                      'Picks up the file name present in the cell

          Fname = MyCell.Value                   'Assigns the value of the cell to fname

          Set searchWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\" & Fname, True, True)
          Set searchSheet = searchWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'get a reference to the sheet to be searched

          Find_String searchSheet, copyToSheet                               'calls the search code with the referenece sheet
          searchWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

       End If


     Next
     copyToWorkbook.Close True
End Sub

Sub Find_String(searchSheet As Worksheet, copyToSheet As Worksheet)

    Dim FirstAddress As String
    Dim MySearch As Variant
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim I As Long
    Dim strMyValue As String
    Dim Axis
    Dim foundCell As Range


    MySearch = Array("D0")                     'value that needs to be searched

    With searchSheet.Range("B1:H100")

    For I = LBound(MySearch) To UBound(MySearch)

       Set Rng = .Find(What:=MySearch(I), After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                           LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
      If Not Rng Is Nothing Then      'this is the part not working
                                      'It should return the search value instead it returns nothing
                 'so as the value returned by the code is nothing and hence the code goes to endif

       FirstAddress = Rng.Address

           Do


              strMyValue = Rng.Offset(0, 6).Value 'Copying the offset value of the located cell
              Axis = Rng.Offset(0, 3).Value
              copyToSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = strMyValue
              copyToSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Axis

             Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
             Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress
           End If
       Next I


    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Nathan.

Also, always avoid `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` with mix of `ActiveWorkbook`, `ActiveSheet`, `ActiveCell`.

Your Find_String should reference the object instead of just range of the activeworkbook

`Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value`

```
Set oWSResult = Workbooks("book22.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet2")
oWSResult.Range("B" & ...
```

It is hard to debug if you presume the active objects are always the one you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a revamped version of the code.  This should run more quickly, and the FindAll function is a bit more versatile.

```
Sub MyMacro()

    Dim wbDest As Workbook
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim wsFileNames As Worksheet
    Dim DataBookCell As Range
    Dim rngCopy As Range
    Dim CopyCell As Range
    Dim arrData(1 To 65000, 1 To 2) As Variant
    Dim MySearch As Variant
    Dim varFind As Variant
    Dim BookIndex As Long
    Dim DataIndex As Long

    Set wbDest = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsFileNames = wbDest.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDest = wbDest.Sheets("Sheet2")
    MySearch = Array("D0")

    For Each DataBookCell In wsFileNames.Range("A1", wsFileNames.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Cells
        If Len(Dir("C:\Users\" & DataBookCell.Text)) > 0 And Len(DataBookCell.Text) > 0 Then
            With Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\" & DataBookCell.Text)
                For Each varFind In MySearch
                    Set rngCopy = FindAll(varFind, .Sheets(1).Range("B1:H100"))
                    If Not rngCopy Is Nothing Then
                        For Each CopyCell In rngCopy.Cells
                            DataIndex = DataIndex + 1
                            arrData(DataIndex, 1) = CopyCell.Offset(, 3).Value
                            arrData(DataIndex, 2) = CopyCell.Offset(, 6).Value
                        Next CopyCell
                    End If
                Next varFind
                .Close False
            End With
        End If
    Next DataBookCell

    If DataIndex > 0 Then wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(DataIndex, UBound(arrData, 2)).Value = arrData

    Set wbDest = Nothing
    Set wsFileNames = Nothing
    Set wsDest = Nothing
    Set DataBookCell = Nothing
    Set rngCopy = Nothing
    Set CopyCell = Nothing
    Erase arrData
    If IsArray(MySearch) Then Erase MySearch

End Sub

Public Function FindAll(ByVal varFind As Variant, ByVal rngSearch As Range, _
                        Optional ByVal LookIn As XlFindLookIn = xlValues, _
                        Optional ByVal LookAt As XlLookAt = xlWhole, _
                        Optional ByVal MatchCase As Boolean = False) As Range

    Dim rngAll As Range
    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim strFirst As String

    Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(varFind, rngSearch.Cells(rngSearch.Cells.Count), LookIn, LookAt, MatchCase:=MatchCase)
    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
        strFirst = rngFound.Address
        Set rngAll = rngFound
        Do
            Set rngAll = Union(rngAll, rngFound)
            Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(varFind, rngFound, LookIn, LookAt, MatchCase:=MatchCase)
        Loop While rngFound.Address <> strFirst
        Set FindAll = rngAll
    Else
        Set FindAll = Nothing
    End If

    Set rngAll = Nothing
    Set rngFound = Nothing

End Function
```